# Dynamics CRM SDK : Unsecured fault in the long run

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

I have a job written in C# that uses the Dynamics SDK 2016 to feed quite a lot of data into an on-premise Dynamics CRM. It's basically all `OrgProxy.Create()`'s and `Associate`'s using the same OrganizationServiceProxy instance all the way. At first everything goes fine, but after an hour or so, every command I send fails with

> an unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party

Then if I stop and re-run the program immediately, it does the same thing all over again - work perfectly during the first hour but reject it all after.

I enabled the logs on the Dynamics server but they contain nothing relevant to that problem. I tried to delete or rename `LiveDevice.xml` as suggested in many places, but the file is nowhere to be found on my machine. Also looked at various CRM settings in IIS, Deployment Manager and the Dynamics interface proper - none seems to point to a specific timeout period or max connection time that would match my problem.

Has anyone experienced this or even have the vaguest idea why Dynamics would start complaining only after X amount of time ? All similar problems I have read about so far seem to fail right from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An hour is pretty short, but I believe I've seen this in the past when running over night apps because the auth token expires (although I'm pretty sure there was a more descriptive error). Run fiddler and take a look at at the initial auth call to see what the expiration date is on the token coming back, specifically looking for something like the following:

```
<trust:Lifetime>
    <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        2016-08-12T13:08:20.839Z
    </wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        2016-08-13T13:08:20.839Z
    </wsu:Expires>
</trust:Lifetime>
```

If it is an hour from the issue timestamp then that might be your issue.

Comment: It was exactly that. I did `Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Targetname "relying_party" -TokenLifetime 600` and no more errors. Thank you Matt.